# store.connect() is not working for gmail imap on proxy

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, imap, network-protocols

`store.connect()` is not working for gmail imap on proxy for my below code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", email, pass);
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

Getting below error:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection refused: connect; nested
>   exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Already tried:

1. http://developers.viafirma.com/en/proxy-connection-problems-connection-refused
2. [JavaMail SMTP-host error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428254/javamail-smtp-host-error)
3. http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/02/java-net-ConnectException-Connection-refused.html

Comment: What is your error or traceback?

Comment: @Max: javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection refused: connect;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved when I have used below code for proxy and port:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("http.proxySet", "true");
props.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
props.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", email, pass);
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

Comment: Which country proxy host are you using?